# Qt: LNK2001 and LNK2019 Errors arise after implementing a signal/slot across source files

Tags: c++, qt, linker, qt-creator

This consists of the declarations in my MainWindow file, I haven't included the library inclusions for brevity. I have included QObject.h in both, and all required libraries. It was compiling fine before the inclusion of the second connect call. The first Ctrl-C handler works fine.

`I took out my code, thought my employer wouldn't like it. See the appropriate response below!`

I am using QT Creator. When I googled these error messages, most of the solutions provided revolved around fixing the make command/path or something of the sort which occurs when compiled in Visual Studio.

I reiterate, these errors showed up ONLY after the inclusion of that second connect call of the global GCamera and the MainWindow. The program was compiling and running before this.

Thank you in advance, I apologize for the lengthy post and look forward to receiving any input.

Comment: Why are you using header guards around the QObject #include? Also, have you tried running qmake? Last, have you added `#include "tcamera.h"` (or whatever that header file is called) in the file containing your MainWindow constructor?

Comment: Yes I have. I just thought it would be safer to include header guards, the way I understand it, there's no harm by including them right? 
Unless there's something wrong there, all the includes have been taken care off of. Besides, linker issues would've been raised before that connect was implemented if it was a dependency issue... I have not tried qmake though, let me try that.

Comment: Typically you include header guards at the top of a header file to ensure that the classes declared (not subclassed) in that file are not declared more than once. Try removing the guards and see what happens.

Comment: I tried this on both files (both include QObject), and this does not change anything. The guards shouldn't affect anything, they're just padding to protect things from being included twice or so.

Comment: Since this is a linker issue, it would be helpful to see both header files in their entirety.

Comment: Hey Anthony,I just put up most of the files in contention in their entirety. The header and the cpp files, let me know if anything pops out at you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a file named `moc_tcamera.cpp` that implements the missing symbol in the build directory.

If it isn't present, you should "run qmake", and "Rebuild" your project (both actions are in Qt Creator Build menu).

#### Why the error occured:

qmake adds a moc (Qt's meta object compiler) step to the Makefile for all the source files that contains the macros `Q_OBJECT` or `Q_GADGET`, such file is said to be "mocable". Once a file is detected as mocable or non mocable, that status doesn't change until qmake is rerun.

QtCreator only runs qmake by itself when the .pro file changes (for example, when you add or remove a file).

It means you probably compiled the project once without the `Q_OBJECT` macro in the file `tcamera.h`, and added that macro afterward. And because you didn't need the meta object until you added the call to `connect`, VC++ didn't try to resolve the missing symbols.

Comment: This did take care of the errors... But can you tell me what running qmake does? And why an error like that would arise? Thank you.

Comment: I was wondering whether you could explain why that error pops up and why running qmake does fix it. I'm new to Qt and C++, and that would make for a better answer for anyone stumbling upon this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get linker errors when you, say, include the header in your .pro file, but not the source. For example in your .pro file:

```
HEADERS += t_camera.h foo.h
SOURCES += foo.cpp
```

would cause you to have linker errors, typically LNK2001 and LNK2019. However, IIRC QtCreator manages the .pro files for you, right? In other words, make sure your .pro file is correct. I'd be surprised if it wasn't, but errors in the .pro file can cause the issue you're seeing.

Comment: Ack. Just saw this "..these errors showed up ONLY after the inclusion of that second connect call of the global GCamera and the MainWindow. " so my answer probably won't help you, but I'm leaving it (for now) in the slim chance it's a .pro file issue.

Comment: It's definitely not a PRO issue and the above answer seems to solve it, but I appreciate the response! Thank you.